# How to show with python current day in label

Tags: python

I am trying to get a label in python to show me the text ("Today" + day of the week we are in), the code I implement is:

self.label.setText ("Today" + datetime.date.today ())

but when running the program it gives me an error TypeError: can only concatenate str

I hope someone can help me

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow](http://StackOverflow.com/tour) - Please read our [ask] page and [edit] your question to improve it.
Good questions tend to receive quicker, better answers from the community.

Comment: Try `self.label.setText ("Today " + str(datetime.date.today()))`

Comment: `self.label.setText(f"Today {datetime.date.today()}")` might also work for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the weekday, e.g. Friday, use this:

```
import datetime

...

self.label.setText("Today is " + datetime.date.today().strftime('%A'))
```

This will set the label to e.g. "Today is Friday".

Comment: Thank you very much brother, I can not vote yet but when I have 15 points I will give you my vote

Comment: You're welcome, @DhampirCU! You might still be able to click the checkmark next to it to mark it as accepted.